# How do you deal with runtime data types?

Tags: types, typescript

What's the common practice to type runtime data?
For example, I have a "fields" data that is fields data submitted from a form by internet user.

How do you type it? Just 'any'?

Here is an example object I get from a form submission, but I may have several forms, each with their own fields:

[image]

Comment: It will be best if you'd include an example of the data you refer to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
interface Form {}

interface FormOne extends Form {
    email: string;
    link: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
}
```

Where each form is an interface extending the base `Form` interface.
Or you can do this:

```
interface Form<T extends Fields> {
    url: string;
    fields: T;
}

interface Fields {}

interface FieldsOne extends Fields {
    email: string;
    link: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
}
```

Where you need only to extend the `Fields` interface.

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed properly describe the type. But in a language like typescript where interfaces are virtual, does it still make any sense to type runtime data, when we know it doesn't matter at runtime what the real data type is since there will be no type check.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense because it checks things for development time, it will let you know (with an error) if you're trying to access `myform.titl` when it should be `myform.title`.  As long as you keep your interfaces up to date with your real data then it completely worth the time. Another option of course is to implement the interfaces with classes which are compiled into the js output